# connecting SharePoint list using node js

Tags: node.js, sharepoint

I need to connect my SharePoint list using node. I am making use of the following package sp-request.[sp-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-request)

I am getting the following error.

> Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Here is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sprequest = require('sp-request');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var credentialOptions = {
        username: '****',
        password: '****'
    };
    let spr = sprequest.create(credentialOptions);

    spr.get('https://mysharepoint/sites/mysharepoint/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'MY TITLE\')')
        .then(response => {
            console.log('List Id: ' + response.body.d.Id);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please help me with the error.

Comment: can you share the full error along with the stack trace. I mean something like `at /node_modules/next-routes/dist/index.js:102:27
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7.........`

Comment: to find out exactly on which line you are getting error.

Comment: @RohitWaghela get error on this line `spr.get('https://mysharepoint/sites/mysharepoint/_api`